# I do not know how to evaluate an expression with two?

Tags: c

I am not sure how to evaluate this expression inside the while loop.  I understand that when the statement is true you do the first one and false you do the second but its is confusing me on what I should do when there are two conditional statements.

```
int x = 152487;
int ct1 = 0;
int ct2 = 0;

while(x > 0)
{ x % 2 ? x > 5 ? ct1++ : ct2++ : ct2++;

  x /= 10; 
}

printf("ct1: %d\n", ct1);
printf("ct2: %d\n", ct2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Parenthesize the expression and it will be clear.

```
x % 2 ? (x > 5 ? ct1++ : ct2++) : ct2++;
```

If `x` is odd, then `x % 2` evaluates to `true`. This means the value of the above expression is

```
(x > 5 ? ct1++ : ct2++)
```

which is again a conditional expression. If `x` is even, the expression evaluates to

```
ct2++
```